# EPERM: operation not permitted while initializing knex

Tags: knex.js

whenever i try to initialize the knex module , iam getting this error . Can anyone help me out ?

```
% npx knex init
node:fs:1517
  const result = binding.readdir(
                         ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/Users/karansinghrawat/Desktop'
    at readdirSync (node:fs:1517:26)
    at module.exports (/Users/karansinghrawat/Desktop/knexnode/knex-nodejs/node_modules/escalade/sync/index.js:13:23)
    at findUpConfig (/Users/karansinghrawat/Desktop/knexnode/knex-nodejs/node_modules/knex/bin/utils/cli-config-utils.js:188:10)
    at invoke (/Users/karansinghrawat/Desktop/knexnode/knex-nodejs/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:103:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/karansinghrawat/Desktop/knexnode/knex-nodejs/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:475:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12) {
  errno: -1,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/Users/karansinghrawat/Desktop'
}
```

the knex module is not initializing for postgres

Comment: Please include the code that leads to this error.